# Index - Match using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup, data-munging

I have the following 2 data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates': ['02-Jan','03-Jan','30-Jan'],
    'currency': ['aud','gbp','eur'],
    'amount': [100,330,500]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates': ['01-Jan','02-Jan','03-Jan','30-Jan'],
    'aud': [0.72,0.73,0.74,0.71],
    'gbp': [1.29,1.30,1.4,1.26],
    'eur': [1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18]
})
```

I want to obtain the intersection of `df1.dates` & `df1.currency`. For eg: Looking up the prevalent `'aud'` exchange rate on '02-Jan'

It can be solved using the `Index + Match` functionality of excel. What shall be the best way to replicate it in Pandas.

Desired Output: add a new column `'price'`

```
dates  currency amount price
02-Jan aud      100    0.73
03-Jan gbp      330    1.4
30-Jan eur      500    1.18
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output, or the equivalent Excel code? It's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for from the description.

Comment: Updated the desired output @shadowtalker

Answer (score 4):

The best equivalent of INDEX MATCH is `DataFrame.lookup`:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('dates')
df1['price'] = df2.lookup(df1['dates'], df1['currency'])
```

Comment: Gives me the following error : 'One or more row labels was not found'

Comment: @VirajDesai it works with the data you posted. If this gives you an error, you need to provide data that reproduces the error.

Comment: I had a few lookup values which were missing. This is resolved now.Thanks!

Comment: Deprecated since version 1.2.0: DataFrame.lookup is deprecated, use DataFrame.melt and DataFrame.loc instead. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup

Comment: @Pherdindy huh, that's disappointing. Why was it deprecated?

Comment: @shadowtalker No idea, I was just looking for solutions and noticed it was deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Reshaping your `df2` makes it a lot easier to do a straightforward merge:

```
In [42]: df2.set_index("dates").unstack().to_frame("value")
Out[42]:
            value
    dates
aud 01-Jan   0.72
    02-Jan   0.73
    03-Jan   0.74
    30-Jan   0.71
gbp 01-Jan   1.29
    02-Jan   1.30
    03-Jan   1.40
    30-Jan   1.26
eur 01-Jan   1.15
    02-Jan   1.16
    03-Jan   1.17
    30-Jan   1.18
```

In this form, you just need to match the `df1` fields with `df2`'s new index as such:

```
In [43]: df1.merge(df2.set_index("dates").unstack().to_frame("value"), left_on=["currency", "dates"], right_index=True)
Out[43]:
    dates currency  amount  value
0  02-Jan      aud     100   0.73
1  03-Jan      gbp     330   1.40
```

You can also left merge it if you don't want to lose missing data (I had to fix your `df1` a little for this:

```
In [44]: df1.merge(df2.set_index("dates").unstack().to_frame("value"), left_on=["currency", "dates"], right_index=True, how="left")
Out[44]:
    dates currency  amount  value
0  02-Jan      aud     100   0.73
1  03-Jan      gbp     330   1.40
2  04-Jan      eur     500    NaN
```

Comment: It is giving me a KeyError:Date What I am missing here?

Comment: It sounds like the column in your actual data might be named `Date` rather than `dates`.

Comment: Hey! I checked this out. There was an error related to index assignment. Thanks!